# Does my computer have an expansion slot for a graphics card?

Tags: agp

I'm trying to get my hands on an usable gaming computer but don't have a lot of money to play with. It seems like I should be able to play recent games on the lowest settings with a new graphics card, but I'm finding the process of figuring that out kind of daunting.

This is the computer I have, right now; http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883114080

It's... not absolutely horrible, but stutters too much to be enjoyable on games within the last couple years. But right! The question!

My confusion stems from the slot in its motherboard that LOOKS like an AGP slot (as far as I can tell), but I can't find anything about it in the hardware specs. Am I missing something here? Completely misidentifying the slot? Should I just trust what I'm looking at in the hardware even if it doesn't seem to be noted in the documentation?

Edit; They are indeed PCIe 1 and PCI standard slots. I guess that does narrow down my options quite a bit, but honestly that's sort of a relief. Less to look through and no temptation to spend bazillions of dollars on it. I mostly just want to be able to play some new games on min settings/avoid lag in Corel until I've saved up enough for a better computer down the road.

I guess this is resolved! But hey, if anyone wants to chime in with any specific card recommendations I won't complain.

Thanks, sawdust!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specs do not mention any expansion slots, but the photos seem to show one PCI Express x1 slot and one PCI slot. Both require **low-profile** cards. Your choices are rather limited, but a PCI Express x1 card would probably be a better selection if you want to later use it in another mobo or PC.

**Edit:**
Check the BIOS configuration setting for "disabling the integrated GPU".  The alternate selection(s) may state the type(s) of the expansion slots.

Comment: Yep. Your choices would be graphics cards like this [PCIe x1 HD4350 low profile card](http://www.amazon.com/Radeon-HD4350-Retail-Graphics-900308/dp/B0038LWTUW), and running that on your 220 watt power supply is going to be very, very scary.

Answer (score 0):

It is **very** unlikely that you have an AGP slot. Either it's a PCI or PCIe. The only reason that motherboard could have an AGP slot, is if the motherboard is custom built with that function in mind, but that's so rare that I only know about 1 motherboard from Asrock that does it.

Comment: The age of the computer was not stated, so an answer/guess based on your familiarity of current production has dubious value.

Comment: I have to downvote this answer because of the comment about the AGP slot being "unlikely" its perfectly "likely" the slot itself was only retired a few years ago.

Comment: I see your point since i didn't elaborate on why I stated that it was "very unlikely". The computer uses an 6150 chipset. That tells us something about how old or modern the motherboard is and what technology can be used in conjunction with it. The PCEe slot is almost exclusively used for that chipset/platform, although there are rare cases where AGP is necessary. I realize that my answer is not conclusive, only guiding. My bad. I do, however, disagree with you on that the use of the AGP slot for that motherboard generation is "perfectly likely".